# How to align the search button to the right of search box

Tags: html, css, form-control

How do I align the button to the right of the text box, after using form control on the search box, I am able to align the button to the left of the text box but I wish to have it on the right, please help.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-4 pull-left">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="New" onclick="go('password_det.asp');" />
    </div>
    <div class ="form-group pull-right"> 
       <input class="form-control" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" placeholder="Search" aria-controls="example1" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
       <button class="btn" type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Search" onclick="showContent('page=1');return false;">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
       </button>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

[The search box and button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhiNE.jpg)

Comment: seems you are using bootstrap, try using input group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix again!

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-4 pull-left">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="New" onclick="go('password_det.asp');" />
    </div>   
    <div class="pull-right">
       <button class="btn" type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Search" onclick="showContent('page=1');return false;">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
       </button>
    </div> 
    <div class ="form-group pull-right"> 
       <input class="form-control" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" placeholder="Search" aria-controls="example1" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `style=float: right;` on button tag to align button to right and then adjust margin and padding accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try Input Groups on the `form` elements, bootstrap by default provides those classes

This is how you make use of them

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-4 pull-left">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="New" onclick="go('password_det.asp');" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 pull-right">
    <div class ="input-group search-bar"> 

       <input class="form-control" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" placeholder="Search" aria-controls="example1" type="text" />
       <span class="input-group-addon">
       <button class="btn search-btn" type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Search" onclick="showContent('page=1');return false;">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
       </button>
       </span>
    </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.search-bar{
  padding:0;
}
.search-bar .input-group-addon{
  padding:0;
}
.search-bar .search-btn{
  padding:5px  12px;
}
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/2e97u9do/3/)

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

**Just change place them:**

**Change:**

```
<div class ="form-group pull-right"> 
     <input class="form-control" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" placeholder="Search" aria-controls="example1" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
   <button class="btn" type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Search" onclick="showContent('page=1');return false;">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
   </button>
</div>
```

**To:**

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <button class="btn" type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Search" onclick="showContent('page=1');return false;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class ="form-group pull-right"> 
    <input class="form-control" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" placeholder="Search" aria-controls="example1" type="text" />
</div>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-4 pull-left">
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="New" onclick="go('password_det.asp');" />
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
       <button class="btn" type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Search" onclick="showContent('page=1');return false;">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
       </button>
    </div>
    <div class ="form-group pull-right"> 
       <input class="form-control" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" placeholder="Search" aria-controls="example1" type="text" />
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of inline search form:

```
<div class="pull-right">
          <form method="get" action="">
            <div class="form-group form-inline">
              <input type="text" placeholder="search" class="form-control" name="s">
              <button title="search" name="search" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```